# Binding to IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding

```
Binding={Binding Source={x:Static ...}}
```

doesn't seem to work, so my static wrapper class doesn't work.

How can we make a two-way binding to a key in WP7 `IsolatedStorageSettings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is wondering, I built a non-static class, which had non-static properties that were simply aliases for the static properties. I then made an instance of it, and added it as a resource to App.xaml, then bound against that resource. This also allows you to add properties like VisibleIfTrial etc.